# As a British citizen , married to a non EU who has UK permanent resident card can travel together to italy?

Tags: schengen, italy, eu, family

My husband is non-EU , but holding a Uk residence permit card without bearing or written in Resident Card  as member of EEA family member. Can he still travel with me in Italy ?

Comment: The directive uses "United Kingdom “Article 10″ residence card issued to the Moroccan spouse of a Belgian citizen" as the very example of someone not needing a visa...

Comment: @chx: It is not an Article 10 card unless it says "family member of an EEA/union citizen".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he can travel with you to Italy, but if he is not a national of a visa-exempt country, he needs a visa.  The Italian consulate must grant the visa unless your husband's visit would be a threat to public safety or health, or against public policy.

The visa is free of charge and the application must be considered by an "expedited" procedure.